# Field Mapping for callout Object - JSON

Tags: apex, field-mapping

I am having nearly 400+ fields in a object and during callout I have to send this fields in JSON body.

At present I am manually mapping the fields by keeping all the JSON fields in a object.So the clas itself is having nearly 400+ fields

So mapping like this

```
Health_SBP__c ----> fv_sbp
Health_DBP__c ----> fv_dbp
...
```

Not sure whether my mapping will create any performance issue?. Is there a batter way to map these 400 + fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to map those values, you'll have to deal with 400+ executions. A typical way to do this is to create a Field Map type object (e.g. as a [Custom Metadata Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_about.htm&type=5)), grab the CMTs in to a list, and then iterate over those values as you create your JSON. This gives you a configurable way to add/remove fields without modifying code later. There's plenty of examples available on this site and around the Internet that go in to more detail on how to do this.